# Joomla Extension Manager issue - Getting an HTTP 500 Server error

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, http-error, server-error

I am using Joomla on my website. Now when i try to access the Extension Manager under Extensions, it gives me the following server error

```
The website encountered an error while retrieving 
http://myURL/upload/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer. 
It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
```

How do i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: It isn't clear from the info provided - is your site in a folder called /upload/ or is that a typo. Do all other pages within the /administrator/ area work okay - is this the only error? What do your server's error logs show - 500 errors generally get entries in the error log with more details.

Comment: Thanks Dean - Well yes, uploads is part of the url when logging into my backend..All other features on Joomla work okay, only the Extesnions manager that gives this error, or any other extension functionality...

Comment: So is the site itself in the root of the FTP and the *administrator* folder located in the *uploads* folder? Or is the whole site located in the *uploads* folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely find more information in the error log, but a few things to look at are:

1. permissions: com_installer may need the tmp folder to be writable
2. configuration: is your tmp folder configured properly (you can check in system information)
3. corruption: try reinstalling the update package of Joomla over your current installation (the update package) with ftp/shell
4. improper routing configuration: you may have some wrong configuration either in your httpd.conf or .htaccess file (try renaming them quickly to see if this is the issue; look for an .htaccess in the administrator folder, and each parent up to the web root (so ./uploads/administrator, ./uploads, . )

I repeat, reading the error log (apache error_log or php error, or turn on debug in Joomla) should give you more than enough information to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I had forgotten to rename **htaccess.txt** to **.htaccess**